# Starting a batch command on a remote Windows system using WMI

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmi

is there a way to start a cmd shell process ( a *.bat file ) on a remote Windows system via WMI ?

Local system is Windows 7 Enterprise and Access-VBA.

Remote system is Windows Server 2008/2012.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NODE` switch:

```
WMIC process call create notepad /NODE:Other-machine  /USER  other-machine\user /PASSWORD pass
```

if the user is common for both machines you can skip the user and the password.
Mind that this will fail if executed against localhost.

To start a batch file

```
WMIC process call create "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c \"c:\scripts\some.bat\"","c:\scripts" /NODE:Other-machine  /USER  other-machine\user /PASSWORD pass
```

On successful run the wmic should return the PID of the created process.